# get direction in NSEW of a target location in android

Tags: android, gps, location, direction

I want to get the direction of a location in NSEW form. The direction should be from current to target location.
if I enter two locations in form of latitude and longitude then It will return direction like that

- N
- S
- E
- W
- NE
- SE
- NW
- SW

Comment: You actually need to define these things a bit more.  How much of an angle west are you allowed before you consider it "NW" rather than N?  Or W rather than NW?  Location has a bearingTo function that will give you degrees East of true North to get to that point, with that angle and the definition of the various divisions you can write a trivial function to get the answer

Comment: well that can be adjusted but first the function should at least gives NSEW.